# How to change CSS to scale page correct for full width

Tags: css, zooming, scale, html

I have a problem with my website, where when opening the site on an iPad it does not scale to full with of all elements, on the right side the page is cropped.
But after zoom out (pinch) the page is displayed as it should.

My site uses this theme:
http://cubicthemes.com/develop/veteranfood/

Developers of the theme cannot help me :-(
I hope someone else can help to solve this (CSS?) issue?

Comment: you are using responsive css like @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) correct?

Comment: yes, its a responsive css (as far as I know), I did buy the theme and use it as is, but think it needs some tweaking to display correct on ipad browsers

Answer (score 0):

Which generation of iPad giving you trouble?

Try the following
Adjust view port in the head of each page (easy)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1020px"/>
```

Or not so easy is to start playing with CSS media tags in `style.css`